# Best way to build floor above blacktop

Tags: flooring

I am wanting to finish out my garage into a living space. The garage is a converted carport and the ground is still blacktop, despite there being walls up around it. What's the best way to handle the floor? Should I be framing something on top of the blacktop? Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what is next to the garage and if there is something what the height of the floor is compared to your garage?

Comment: The garage is connected to the house. The are currently three steps up to the house. Does that help?

Comment: So, it would be fine to raise the height of the floor, and there is plenty of ceiling height. Just not sure what exactly to build, or if it's doable. Thanks @DMoore

Comment: So the garage is a good 2-3 feet below the house level?  And the height in the garage is 10 feetish?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right

Comment: What are the walls sitting on? Is there an actual foundation around the perimeter of this carport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with just the blacktop you basically need to jackhammer up some holes in the floor so that you can pour footings.  You can frame out the area much like you would a deck.  This is given that the walls of the garage are above proper footings.  How many footings you need is dependent on how big your garage is.  How deep the footings are, is dependent of your climate.

Also I would try to match up the floor to the floor in your house.  But all inspectors I know want ceilings to be at least 7 feet.  How close you can match these areas up is depended on your garage ceiling height and what you local town lets you do.

Comment: Depends on the age/type/condition of the blacktop, but sometimes a pick or shovel can make quick work of blacktop.

Comment: I'd go with removing ALL the blacktop - it's not really something you want inside the house.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Who knows what is under the blacktop.  Often it is bad concrete.  At least from my parts.  I would install a vapor barrier under floor decking to keep blacktop out of house.  Removing it might be the best way to go about it but might quadruple the costs.  Also removing it would probably mean ruining the garage walls.